# Asking game decisions input to players through a Python discord bot

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio

I want to play a board game (named "Cyclades") online with friends. I wrote the game logic using Python, in a `CycladesLogic` class, which at that time received the players' decisions through the console. Then I created a modest graphic interface using Pygame, in a `CycladesUI` class, so that the players' decisions come from mouse buttons. This allows us to play the game with all players on the same computer.
The next step is to play it online on different computers, but as I know nothing of web applications, I want first to try to play it through a Discord bot. So I have a discord bot (again in a `CycladesBot` class) that creates an instance of `CycladesLogic` when given the command "!game". Then the `CycladesLogic` proceeds through the different steps of the game, and eventually will have to ask a decision to a player, who answers by writing the decision in Discord, as if it were the console.

However I was not able to have the `CycladesLogic` instance receive the player's answer for that decision, because :

1. I can't use the "on_message" methods or commands-triggered methods of the discord bot to call methods of `CycladesLogic`. I saw how it is possible to make a Tictactoe through a discord bot that way : the players have a command "!place" to place their mark, and the logic of the game is entirely managed by the methods triggered by the command. But for a more complex game like Cyclades, I need the `CycladesLogic` object following the state of the game with its own successive methods, asking questions, instead of reacting to commands.
2. I can't use `answer = await wait_for("message",...)` in `CycladesLogic`, because its methods are synchronous so I get a "SyntaxError" if I put an `await` instruction in them (in fact, I would be very satisfied if I had in the discord bot a blocking input function like `input()` in the console). Neither can I have something like an event loop in `CycladesLogic` that would stop after the bot has registered and answer, again because that loop would be synchronous and would thus prevent the execution of an `on_message()` method of the bot.
3. So I tried to put that loop in a special asynchronous method `wait_answer()` of `CycladesLogic`, tasked to make `asyncio.sleep(some_time)` until the discord bot has an answer to return. I call this asynchronous method with `answer = asyncio.run(self.wait_answer())`. This gives a "RuntimeError: This event loop is already running" since I read you can't have two asyncio loops running at the same time. I saw on other Stack Overflow topics examples of using `nest_asyncio`, but I think this allows only to have 2 separate loops of asyncio, not that these two loops pass priority to each other. I tried anyway to use `nest_asyncio` and I got an error I can't really understand :

```
Exception in callback <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7efee2ff9fa0>(<Future finished result=None>)
handle: <Handle <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7efee2ff9fa0>(<Future finished result=None>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeError: Cannot enter into task <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<Client.run.<locals>.runner() running at /home/administyrateur/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py:817> wait_for=<Future finished result=None> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py:184]>
while another task <Task pending name='discord.py: on_message' coro=<Client._run_event() running at /home/administyrateur/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py:409>> is being executed.
```

Here is the structure of the code I tried in (3), to give an idea :

```
import discord
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio

class CycladesLogic():
    def __init__(self,discordBot):
        nest_asyncio.apply()
        self.discordBot = discordBot # the discord bot that created this instance
    def choose_option(player:Player):
        """Allows player <player> to make a decision."""
        answer = asyncio.run(self.wait_answer())
        return answer
    async def wait_answer():
        """Waits until the discord bot has registered an answer."""
        ans = -1
        while ans == -1:
            await asyncio.sleep(1) # time for the discord bot to register an answer
            ans = await self.discordBot.get_answer()
        return ans

class CycladesBot(discord.Client):
    async def on_message(self,message):
        if not(message.author.bot) and message[0] == "THE COMMAND PREFIX":
            parts = message[1:].split(" ")
            cmd = parts[0]
            if cmd == "game": # start a Cyclades game
                self.cycladesGame = CycladesLogic(self)
                self.answer = -1
            elif com == "answer": # give the decision required by the game
                self.answer = parts[1] # the decision is a simple string
    async def get_answer(self):
        ans = self.answer
        if self.answer != -1: # if the answer is not -1,
            self.answer = -1  # it has to be reset for the nex question
        return ans
```

So my question is :

- Is it even possible that a synchronous game-logic object asks a question to a player through the asynchronous discord bot, or do I have to make all my game-logic code asynchronous ?
- If it is possible, is the solution to make `nest_asyncio` work or is it something else ? Sorry if the solution is trivial, I don't know asyncio very well...
  I am using Python3.9 and async 3.4.3, on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the response to [this bug issue](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/2040).